# Alter String[] length if it is too short

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have a method that gets a SQLite column into String[] form.  I then populate a "Top Ten" list with that data.  If the column has at least 10 rows, everything works fine, however I get an error if the length is less than 10.

I've tried to check for null, but it seems the program crashes trying to check for null on a String[] field that does not exist.  How can I create a new String[] (same name or another name) and just add blank spaces it in order to have a minimum length of 10?

Edit to add:  I still want to populate the top ten list, even if it has less than 10 elements.

Comment: See: [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). There should not be an issue with pulling less that 10 rows, that's the initial problem that should be fixed. You should not be trying to pull more than what exist in the database in the first place.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far because you haven't shown us any code.

Comment: This seems superfluous. Why not just check `array.length` before trying to access elements?

Comment: @mike I still want to populate the top ten list (even id it only has nine elements, for example).

Comment: You are using a data structure that has fixed number of elements. For size growable datastructure use collection framework. Try using ArrayList in this context.

Comment: I'm not sure why the extra elements must have an empty `String` if you're going to assign them values anyway, but you could alter your method to use a `for` loop over the full range, then inside, something like `if (cursor.moveToNext()) { array[i] = cursor.getString(...); } else { array[i] = ""; }`.

Comment: @mike  I tried to do just that, however it seemed to me that when the array got to [i] spot that didn't exist, it would crash.  It wouldn't allow me to set it to "".  Now that I read your comment again, I see your suggesting to to the "" in the SQLite method.. Interesting.  That's a good idea.  I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: If you're initializing the `String` array, and setting the `for` loop bounds, I'm not sure how that's happening. `String[] array = new String[10]; for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { ... }`. Edit - oh, yeah, I meant do that while you're going over the `Cursor`.

Comment: or use the [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(T[],%20int,%20int)) class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using the Arrays class

```
    String oldArr[] = {"one", "two", "three"};

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(oldArr));
    String newArr[] = Arrays.copyOf(oldArr, 10);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArr));
    for (int x = oldArr.length; x < newArr.length; x++) {
        newArr[x] = "unset";
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArr));
```

**output**

```
[one, two, three]
[one, two, three, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[one, two, three, unset, unset, unset, unset, unset, unset, unset]
```

Comment: This also seems superfluous. Why would you introduce a second array, when you can do this all with one? I mean, you still have to loop over every element, so why not just do this all in the first one? Well, whatever works for the OP, I guess.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for your comment.  a) not necessary to loop over every element (see code).  b) Assuming that OP does not have control over the original Array  c) reduces Array to 10 if greater than 10  d)  If OP can check for null element then resetting to some other value here is not required at all.  If you post and answer, it may be better than mine and upvoted to heaven.

Comment: I meant that they're already looping over a `Cursor` to fill the first elements, so after your code, they are looping over every element, just in two separate loops. I outlined the solution to do it one place in my comments above, but I can't really post a specific answer unless the OP gives an MCVE that shows what the problem was to begin with. Anyhoo, I'm not slamming your code, or anything. Just saying that the OP is likely making this more convoluted than necessary. That comment was kinda directed at them anyway. :-) Cheers!

Comment: @MikeM. *I'm not slamming your code* didn't think you were - have a nice day

Answer (score -1):

To answer your last question, you need to initialize the array:

String[] stringArray = {"","","","","","","","","",""};

or if it were larger, you could use a loop:

String[] stringArray = new String[100];
for(int i = 0; i < 100;i++){
    stringArray[i] = "";
}

If you initialize it first, you won't get that exception, HOWEVER you should ALWAYS make sure you aren't trying to read data from an array that isn't there by checking the array length:  stringArray.length .

Comment: I initilaized like you suggested.  Then popuated from db (set to have only 9 item for testing).  I still get this... java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=9; index=9